# NginX rewrite/redirect rule http://www to http://

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I need a basic redirect rule so if someone types: www.site.com will be redirected to site.com. I need it to look neat and clean in the browser.

I tried this in my nginx serverblock:

```
# trying redirects from http://   www.site.com to http://   site.com
if ($host = "www.site.com") {
rewrite ^ $scheme://site.com$uri permanent;
}

...

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @modx-rewrite /index.php?/$request_uri;
    location ~ .php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

But for some reason that didn't work and I get "server not found error".
And also it adds http S in my address.

Without those rules my site opens fine and runs over https and the pages open normally with https: //  site.com links.

Thanks.

NB: I intentionally added several spaces in code snipets in address, otherwise stackoverflow won't let me post it.

Answer (score 1):

Make it simpler:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    location / { .........; }
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    location / { return 301 http://example.com$request_uri; }
}
```